# Can you vary how far Lightning Lure pulls the target toward you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, forced-movement, cantrips

In the description of [*lightning lure*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-lure) (SCAG, p. 143), it says:

> You create a lash of lightning energy that strikes at one creature of your choice that you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pulled **up to 10 feet** in a straight line toward you and then take 1d8 lightning damage if it is within 5 feet of you.

(emphasis mine)

Does that mean that I can vary the distance the creature is pulled? Like am I able to just pull it 5 feet as opposed to 10?

Comment: The quote in your post didn't match the spell description, but the relevant section of the spell description is still worded the same way, so I went ahead and fixed the quote (and added a DNDBeyond link and page number).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## "*Up to*" means exactly that

If you are not paying on a grid, you can pull the target 3.2 feet, or whatever you desire under 10 feet.

However, he does *not* take damage if he is not adjacent to you after the pull.